# Permanent WMI Event consumer doesnt get triggered, temporary does

Tags: windows, events, powershell, wmi

I am trying to create a permanent WMI Event subscription to run a script when a USB Drive gets connected.

Here is how I create the Filter, Consumer and the binding:

```powershell
$computer = "xxx"
$filterNS = "root\cimv2"
$wmiNS = "root\subscription"
$query = "Select * from __InstanceCreationEvent within 5 where targetinstance isa 'win32_logicaldisk'"

$filterName = "TestFilter"

$filterPath = Set-WmiInstance -Class __EventFilter `
 -ComputerName $computer -Namespace $wmiNS -Arguments `
  @{name=$filterName; EventNameSpace=$filterNS; QueryLanguage="WQL";
    Query=$query}

$consumerPath = Set-WmiInstance -Class CommandLineEventConsumer `
 -ComputerName $computer -Namespace $wmiNS `
 -Arguments @{
 name="TestConsumer"; 
 ExecutablePath= "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe";
 CommandLineTemplate = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file D:\\reassignDriveletter.ps1"
 }

Set-WmiInstance -Class __FilterToConsumerBinding -ComputerName $computer `
  -Namespace $wmiNS -arguments @{Filter=$filterPath; Consumer=$consumerPath} |
  out-null
```

Everything gets created without errors, i can see the Filter, consumer and binding in WMI event viewer but if i attach a USB drive nothing happens (first line of the script writes a log entry, thats how i know).

For testing purposes i created a normal event subscription like this:

```powershell
$job = Register-WmiEvent -Query "Select * from __InstanceCreationEvent within 5 where targetinstance isa 'win32_logicaldisk'" -SourceIdentifier usb -Timeout 1000 -Action $scriptblock
```

which works absolutely fine.

Am I missing something obvious? I´d be grateful for any help.

Regards

Update: Just tested on a non-domain joined Win7 Computer and the same code works fine. (My workstation is Win8.1 domain-joined for the record). I will test on the target system and report back.

Comment: This is just a swag but have you tried removing the -Arguments variables and using hard-coded values instead e.g. `-arguments @{name="TestFilter"; EventNameSpace="root\cimv2";...}`  I'm just wondering if maybe the arguments should be specified in quotes like this `name="$filtername"`.  Also, if you pulled this example from C# it could be that you don't need the double backslashes in your paths for ExecutablePath and CommandLineTemplate.  Backslash is not the escape character in PowerShell.

Comment: @KeithHill just tested with hardcoded values and no double backslashes but that doesnt help either :/ also the variables are not the problem since i can see the values in wmi viewer are correct

Answer (score 1):

OK, after a couple of days of trial and error, I ended up adapting/using a different approach found [here](http://learn-powershell.net/2013/08/14/powershell-and-events-permanent-wmi-event-subscriptions/).

This will launch a script stored in D:\scripts everytime a USB is connected and it's permanent.

```
$filter = ([wmiclass]"\\.\root\subscription:__EventFilter").CreateInstance()

$filter.QueryLanguage = "WQL"
$filter.Query = "Select * from __InstanceCreationEvent within 5 where targetinstance isa 'win32_logicaldisk'"
$filter.Name = "USBFilter"
$filter.EventNamespace = 'root\cimv2'

$result = $filter.Put()
$filterPath = $result.Path

$consumer = ([wmiclass]"\\.\root\subscription:CommandLineEventConsumer").CreateInstance()
$consumer.Name = 'USBConsumer'
$consumer.CommandLineTemplate = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe –ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file D:\scripts\reassignDriveletter.ps1"
$consumer.ExecutablePath = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
$consumer.WorkingDirectory = "D:\scripts"
$result = $consumer.Put()
$consumerPath = $result.Path

$bind = ([wmiclass]"\\.\root\subscription:__FilterToConsumerBinding").CreateInstance()

$bind.Filter = $filterPath
$bind.Consumer = $consumerPath
$result = $bind.Put()
$bindPath = $result.Path
```

To delete these Perma Events, do this:

```
([wmi]$filterPath).Delete()
([wmi]$consumerPath).Delete()
([wmi]$bindPath).Delete()
```

My test script created a folder every time a USB drive was plugged in, so I could test it and it worked.

I'm running Windows 8.1 btw.

Comment: Hi Micky, thank you for your efforts. I just tested this and i begin to suspect there is a problem with my workstation since your approach doesnt work either (as stated in my update my script actually works on another machine). I have yet to test any of the scripts on the target machine so until then i suppose both of them work fine

Comment: I just saw that update. Btw, there are security considerations if you created the events with a domain account. Basically that account needs to be member of local admins group, more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393016(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: yes i saw that and the account i created the events with is domain and local admin. I also tried using the machines local admin account to create them but no luck either